# ISE for cmd/batch scripts?

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell, batch-file

There a Integrated Scripting Environment for Windows Powershell scripting language but is there a ISE for Windows batch (.bat) scripts? How do people develop .bat scripts efficiently, do you use some kind of ISE?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you have windows xp or older, you could go to the command prompt and type:

```
edit test.bat
```

It should bring up a blue screen with a very primitive GUI that lets you open, edit, and create batch files. It also has a list (along with detailed descriptions) of every command used in both batch/shell programming and power shell programming. This program is also available in windows server 2003 and later last time i checked! :P

Comment: [There is no edit included in 64 bit versions of Windows](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/the-hidden-text-editor-in-windows-7). I was unaware that there was a command reference in edit. This is good to know. Also, according to that link edit was a dos executable. I will have to verify that.

Answer (score 1):

I just use a standard (but decent) text editor - my personal one is vim, but there's others out there (Programmers Text Editor, Notepad+, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manipulate a copy of PowerShell ISE using a *.exe editor, for example Resource Hacker, to implement the Batch scripting language instead of PowerShell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).